# Вылетает приложение ExceptionCode=0xc0000005

Tags: java, исключения

Не могу понять как это вылечить, поиски в гугл не увенчались успехом. Пишут нужно запускать от админа удалить обновления список перечисляют

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000073c66adf, pid=1636, tid=0x00000000000009e4
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: D:\Install\PrintServer\PrintWithJava_jar\hs_err_pid1636.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001dfcd000):  JavaThread "Thread-3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2532, stack(0x00000000200b0000,0x00000000201b0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000005fa7e0c

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000005fa7e0c, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000005fa7e0c, RDX=0x000000001f514680
RSP=0x00000000201af048, RBP=0x00000000201af138, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x000000001dfcd1f8
R8 =0x0000000080100c02, R9 =0x1fffffffffffffff, R10=0x0000000000000001, R11=0x0000000000000003
R12=0x000000001f514688, R13=0x000000001c1ec250, R14=0x00000000201af158, R15=0x000000001dfcd000
RIP=0x0000000073c66adf, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010293

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000201af048)
0x00000000201af048:   0000000073683262 00000000201af138
0x00000000201af058:   000000001f514680 0000000000000004
0x00000000201af068:   000000001dfcd1f8 00000000000000c8
0x00000000201af078:   00000000201af0e8 00000000201af0e0
0x00000000201af088:   0000000000000001 0000000000000000
0x00000000201af098:   000000001c1ec250 fffffffffffffffe
0x00000000201af0a8:   0000000000000000 000000001fb3edc0
0x00000000201af0b8:   0000000000000000 0000000002c97da0
0x00000000201af0c8:   0000000002ca79b4 000000001fb3edc0
0x00000000201af0d8:   000000000000001c 0000000000000003
0x00000000201af0e8:   0000000000000248 000000000000006e
0x00000000201af0f8:   00000000201af0f8 0000000000000000
0x00000000201af108:   00000000201af158 000000001fb3f768
0x00000000201af118:   0000000000000000 000000001fb3edc0
0x00000000201af128:   0000000000000000 00000000201af158
0x00000000201af138:   00000000201af1b8 0000000002c980e0 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000073c66adf)
0x0000000073c66abf:   99 03 00 cc 33 c0 48 8b 5c 24 40 48 8b 74 24 48
0x0000000073c66acf:   48 83 c4 30 5f c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 48 8b c1
0x0000000073c66adf:   0f b7 10 48 83 c0 02 66 85 d2 75 f4 48 2b c1 48
0x0000000073c66aef:   d1 f8 48 ff c8 c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 45 33 c0 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000005fa7e0c is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000005fa7e0c is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000001f514680 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00000000201af048 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001dfcd000
RBP=0x00000000201af138 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001dfcd000
RSI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000001dfcd1f8 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000080100c02 is an unknown value
R9 =0x1fffffffffffffff is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
R12=0x000000001f514688 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000001c1ec250 is an unknown value
R14=0x00000000201af158 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001dfcd000
R15=0x000000001dfcd000 is a thread


Stack: [0x00000000200b0000,0x00000000201b0000],  sp=0x00000000201af048,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.getAllPrinterNames()[Ljava/lang/String;+0
j  sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.refreshServices()V+2
j  sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.access$200(Lsun/print/Win32PrintServiceLookup;)V+1
j  sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup$PrinterChangeListener.run()V+29
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x000000001dfcd000 JavaThread "Thread-3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2532, stack(0x00000000200b0000,0x00000000201b0000)]
  0x000000001e144800 JavaThread "Thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=4040, stack(0x000000001ed60000,0x000000001ee60000)]
  0x000000000298e000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=732, stack(0x0000000002b90000,0x0000000002c90000)]
  0x000000001e142000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=764, stack(0x000000001ebb0000,0x000000001ecb0000)]
  0x000000001e13d000 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2396, stack(0x000000001e960000,0x000000001ea60000)]
  0x000000001e13a000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=4024, stack(0x000000001eaa0000,0x000000001eba0000)]
  0x000000001e139000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2740, stack(0x000000001e830000,0x000000001e930000)]
  0x000000001ddf0800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2152, stack(0x000000001daf0000,0x000000001dbf0000)]
  0x000000001c1ef000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3592, stack(0x000000001e490000,0x000000001e590000)]
  0x000000001c1ee000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2932, stack(0x000000001e260000,0x000000001e360000)]
  0x000000001c1e6800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1864, stack(0x000000001dc70000,0x000000001dd70000)]
  0x000000001c1e4000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1552, stack(0x000000001d9c0000,0x000000001dac0000)]
  0x000000001c1e0800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=980, stack(0x000000001d850000,0x000000001d950000)]
  0x000000001c1c9000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3692, stack(0x000000001d160000,0x000000001d260000)]
  0x000000001c181800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3096, stack(0x000000001d320000,0x000000001d420000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000001c179800 VMThread [stack: 0x000000001d030000,0x000000001d130000] [id=2488]
  0x000000001de16800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000001e6c0000,0x000000001e7c0000] [id=3308]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 74240K, used 64683K [0x000000076d900000, 0x0000000776a00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 64000K, 85% used [0x000000076d900000,0x0000000770e2e9a0,0x0000000771780000)
  from space 10240K, 99% used [0x0000000771780000,0x000000077217c530,0x0000000772180000)
  to   space 10240K, 0% used [0x0000000776000000,0x0000000776000000,0x0000000776a00000)
 ParOldGen       total 169472K, used 2712K [0x00000006c8a00000, 0x00000006d2f80000, 0x000000076d900000)
  object space 169472K, 1% used [0x00000006c8a00000,0x00000006c8ca6048,0x00000006d2f80000)
 Metaspace       used 13658K, capacity 13972K, committed 14208K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1516K, capacity 1596K, committed 1664K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000012050000,0x0000000012810000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000ea0b000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006f3fc720
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000013480000, 0x0000000017258000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000017258000, 0x000000001b030000)

Polling page: 0x00000000008b0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=5742Kb max_used=5742Kb free=240017Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002c90000, 0x0000000003240000, 0x0000000011c90000]
 total_blobs=2083 nmethods=1579 adapters=418
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 27982.392 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 1604       3       java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate::engineUpdate (9 bytes)
Event: 27982.392 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 nmethod 1604 0x0000000003227c10 code [0x0000000003227d80, 0x0000000003227fa8]
Event: 27982.428 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 1605       3       java.util.StringTokenizer::<init> (8 bytes)
Event: 27982.428 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 nmethod 1605 0x0000000003227890 code [0x0000000003227a00, 0x0000000003227b88]
Event: 27982.528 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 1606       3       com.sun.crypto.provider.GCTR::<init> (84 bytes)
Event: 27982.528 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 nmethod 1606 0x000000000322dc90 code [0x000000000322dea0, 0x000000000322e8a8]
Event: 32843.014 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 1607       3       sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown::notifyToolkitThreadBusy (8 bytes)
Event: 32843.015 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 nmethod 1607 0x000000000322b7d0 code [0x000000000322b940, 0x000000000322bb08]
Event: 32843.015 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 1608       3       sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown::notifyToolkitThreadFree (8 bytes)
Event: 32843.015 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 nmethod 1608 0x000000000322b3d0 code [0x000000000322b540, 0x000000000322b708]

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 0.753 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 74240K, used 64000K [0x000000076d900000, 0x0000000772b80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 64000K, 100% used [0x000000076d900000,0x0000000771780000,0x0000000771780000)
  from space 10240K, 0% used [0x0000000772180000,0x0000000772180000,0x0000000772b80000)
  to   space 10240K, 0% used [0x0000000771780000,0x0000000771780000,0x0000000772180000)
 ParOldGen       total 169472K, used 0K [0x00000006c8a00000, 0x00000006d2f80000, 0x000000076d900000)
  object space 169472K, 0% used [0x00000006c8a00000,0x00000006c8a00000,0x00000006d2f80000)
 Metaspace       used 7496K, capacity 7724K, committed 7808K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 819K, capacity 869K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 0.762 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 74240K, used 10225K [0x000000076d900000, 0x0000000776a00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 64000K, 0% used [0x000000076d900000,0x000000076d900000,0x0000000771780000)
  from space 10240K, 99% used [0x0000000771780000,0x000000077217c530,0x0000000772180000)
  to   space 10240K, 0% used [0x0000000776000000,0x0000000776000000,0x0000000776a00000)
 ParOldGen       total 169472K, used 2712K [0x00000006c8a00000, 0x00000006d2f80000, 0x000000076d900000)
  object space 169472K, 1% used [0x00000006c8a00000,0x00000006c8ca6048,0x00000006d2f80000)
 Metaspace       used 7496K, capacity 7724K, committed 7808K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 819K, capacity 869K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 277.997 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002f509e0 method=com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.JSONScanner.stringVal()Ljava/lang/String; @ 4
Event: 277.997 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002f4c998 method=com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.JSONScanner.stringVal()Ljava/lang/String; @ 4
Event: 277.997 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002f3319c method=com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.JSONLexerBase.nextToken(I)V @ 186
Event: 277.999 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002e7accc method=java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Z)Ljava/lang/String; @ 153
Event: 698.614 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002f69378 method=com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.deserializer.JavaBeanDeserializer.parseField(Lcom/alibaba/fastjson/parser/DefaultJSONParser;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/re
Event: 739.171 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002f69378 method=com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.deserializer.JavaBeanDeserializer.parseField(Lcom/alibaba/fastjson/parser/DefaultJSONParser;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/re
Event: 1119.494 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Uncommon trap: reason=predicate action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000030e928c method=java.util.regex.Pattern$SliceI.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 21
Event: 1119.634 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002f69378 method=com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.deserializer.JavaBeanDeserializer.parseField(Lcom/alibaba/fastjson/parser/DefaultJSONParser;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/re
Event: 15302.652 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002fc9528 method=java.util.HashMap.putVal(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 203
Event: 27655.804 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Uncommon trap: reason=predicate action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000322aaac method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Slice.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 21

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 27655.904 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000770d203a0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 27982.528 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000770d96958) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 27982.528 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000770d96c08) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 27982.528 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000770d96e88) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 27982.528 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000770d99fc8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 27982.528 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000770d9a278) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 27982.528 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000770d9a4f8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 27982.528 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000770d9a850) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 27982.528 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000770d9ab00) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 27982.528 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000770d9ad80) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]

Events (10 events):
Event: 22005.022 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000002e2a190
Event: 22005.022 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000002e31dd0
Event: 22005.022 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000002e56d50
Event: 22005.054 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000002e5bdd0
Event: 22005.054 Thread 0x000000001c1ef000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000002e5cf90
Event: 22169.851 Thread 0x000000001e144800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000003146f01 sp=0x000000001ee5eaf0
Event: 22169.851 Thread 0x000000001e144800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002cd747f sp=0x000000001ee5e8e0 mode 0
Event: 27655.804 Thread 0x000000001e144800 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff86 fr.pc=0x000000000322aaac
Event: 27655.804 Thread 0x000000001e144800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x000000000322aaac sp=0x000000001ee5e8e0
Event: 27655.804 Thread 0x000000001e144800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002cd582a sp=0x000000001ee5e888 mode 2


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013fc00000 - 0x000000013fc37000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\javaw.exe
0x0000000077740000 - 0x00000000778c7000     C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
0x00000000773e0000 - 0x000000007750d000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007feff4d0000 - 0x000007feff5d9000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007feff380000 - 0x000007feff4c3000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000077510000 - 0x00000000775dd000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007feff950000 - 0x000007feff9b4000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefc780000 - 0x000007fefc979000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.6002.19373_none_151129cef4086113\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007feff9c0000 - 0x000007feffa5c000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007feff5e0000 - 0x000007feff653000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007feff920000 - 0x000007feff94d000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007feff720000 - 0x000007feff822000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000007fefe210000 - 0x000007fefe21d000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.DLL
0x000007feff680000 - 0x000007feff71b000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x0000000073c30000 - 0x0000000073d02000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000006ebe0000 - 0x000000006f47c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef9bd0000 - 0x000007fef9bd9000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007feff060000 - 0x000007feff0a4000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007feff910000 - 0x000007feff917000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefbf70000 - 0x000007fefbfa9000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007feff0b0000 - 0x000007feff288000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007feff830000 - 0x000007feff908000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefbf10000 - 0x000007fefbf65000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEACC.dll
0x000007fefd160000 - 0x000007fefd16b000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x00000000778e0000 - 0x00000000778e9000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00000000744b0000 - 0x00000000744bf000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000074420000 - 0x0000000074449000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.dll
0x0000000074400000 - 0x0000000074416000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefe400000 - 0x000007feff054000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefdfe0000 - 0x000007fefe006000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefdfc0000 - 0x000007fefdfdc000     C:\Windows\system32\Secur32.dll
0x0000000073600000 - 0x0000000073798000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\awt.dll
0x000007fef9ec0000 - 0x000007fef9ed1000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
0x000007fef67f0000 - 0x000007fef6921000     C:\Windows\system32\opengl32.dll
0x000007fef8190000 - 0x000007fef81bd000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x000007fef64e0000 - 0x000007fef65cf000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x000007fef9be0000 - 0x000007fef9be8000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x000007fefe220000 - 0x000007fefe3fc000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x0000000074020000 - 0x0000000074067000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x000007fef7010000 - 0x000007fef7092000     C:\Windows\system32\mscms.dll
0x000007fefa7a0000 - 0x000007fefa7fe000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x00000000743d0000 - 0x00000000743f4000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\sunec.dll
0x000007fef79b0000 - 0x000007fef79f3000     C:\Windows\system32\icm32.dll
0x0000000074330000 - 0x000000007434a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefd4f0000 - 0x000007fefd53f000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefd580000 - 0x000007fefd587000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefd760000 - 0x000007fefd783000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefd710000 - 0x000007fefd755000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x000007fefda60000 - 0x000007fefda9a000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fefd7c0000 - 0x000007fefd7ca000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fefd790000 - 0x000007fefd7bb000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x0000000074310000 - 0x0000000074321000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\nio.dll
0x000007fefd250000 - 0x000007fefd298000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x00000000744a0000 - 0x00000000744ab000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x000007fefd870000 - 0x000007fefd9ab000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefda20000 - 0x000007fefda39000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x0000000073e10000 - 0x0000000073e52000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\t2k.dll
0x000007fef8e40000 - 0x000007fef8f53000     C:\Windows\system32\DBGHELP.DLL

VM Arguments:
java_command: D:\Install\PrintServer\PrintWithJava_jar\printerFX_jar.jar
java_class_path (initial): D:\Install\PrintServer\PrintWithJava_jar\printerFX_jar.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin
USERNAME=Администратор
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows Server 2008 , 64 bit Build 6002 (6.0.6002.19623)

CPU:total 4 (initial active 4) (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, aes, clmul, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 16205176k(12823840k free), swap 32223000k(30360184k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_131-b11), built on Mar 15 2017 01:23:53 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Tue May 23 21:55:32 2017
elapsed time: 39086 seconds (0d 10h 51m 26s)
```

Comment: Stacktrace вроде есть, хотя можете перепроверить отладчиком. Ищите проблему в исходниках OpenJDK или где уж она по stacktrace. Такое бывает иногда, но так или иначе решается.

Comment: Обновиться до версии 8.131 пробовали?

Comment: похоже на то, что крашится jvm. трудно что то посоветовать, без кода. Можете как заметил @defaultlocale  обновить java до последней, если это баг, то он мог быть исправлен, если же это по причине некорректного кода, то разумеется это не поможет.

Comment: Сейчас обновил джаву, жду когда слетит. Ссылка на гит github.com/SantFlamel/printerFX

Comment: Дело в джавамашине. После обновления всё должно работать нормально.

Comment: Обновление не помогло перезалил лог

Comment: Оно же говорит `The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.` Кажется Java тут не совсем виновата. Что-то с функциями во внешних DLL, например `sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.getAllPrinterNames()`. Принтера какие-нибудь в системе есть?

Comment: Да на них идет печать с java